# ORA-13506 An attempt was made to perform operation with an invalid Start/End Snapshot Pair during AWR report creation

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, awr

When I create an AWR Report, the following error occurs:

> ORA-13506
>   Cause: An attempt was made to perform operation with an
>   invalid Start/End Snapshot Pair.

What does this mean, and what should I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_WORKLOAD_REPOSITORY.create_baseline (
    start_snap_id => --ANY Integer Number_Min Value, 
    end_snap_id   => --ANY Integer Number_Max value, ,
    baseline_name => 'batch baseline');
END;
/
```

So here min and max value are already in `DBA_HIST_BASELINE` view. You can't chose random value for snapshot.

Remember value already in oracle system, you can't drop value but not overbound.